# Draw A Grid in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I'm trying to draw two parallel lines. I can draw one line, but when I go to draw the second line, then neither one draws. No idea why.

I have a Line class that looks like this:

```
    #import "Line.h"

    static GLKBaseEffect *effect;

    @implementation Line

    typedef struct {
        GLKVector3 positionCoordinates;
        GLKVector4 colorCoordinates;
    } VertexData;

    VertexData unitLine[] = {
    //{ { position x,   position y, position z}, {red, blue, green, alpha} }
        { { -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} },
        { {  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} }
    };

    - (id) initWithEffect:(GLKBaseEffect *) effect {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.effect = effect;

        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

        glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unitLine), unitLine, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (GLubyte *)0 + offsetof(VertexData, positionCoordinates));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (GLubyte *)0 + offsetof(VertexData, normalCoordinates));

        glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

    }

    return self;
}

- (GLuint) getVertexArray
{
    return _vertexArray;
}

- (void) render {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
}

- (void) update {

}

- (void) tearDown
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
}

@end
```

Then, in GLKview, I attempt to draw these two lines like this:

In ViewController.m, I have this:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    GLuint _program, _program1;
    GLint i;
    GLfloat j;

    GLKMatrix4 _modelViewProjectionMatrix;
    GLfloat _model_translate_x;
    GLfloat _model_translate_y;
    GLfloat _model_translate_z;

    Cube *my_cube;
    Line *my_line[20]; // for the grid lines    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        my_line[i] = [[Line alloc] initWithEffect: self.effect];
    }
    ...
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    ...
    modelViewMatrix =  GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(_model_translate_x, _model_translate_y, _model_translate_z);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(modelViewMatrix, 10.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glBindVertexArrayOES( [my_line[0] getVertexArray] ); 
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelViewMatrix, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    [my_line[0] render];

    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    [my_line[1] render];
}
```

If I comment out the very last line, then I get one line. If I leave it in, I get no lines. In either case, I also get a console error message 0x0502. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE: I have other objects that are drawn previous to this code. Heretofore, these objects were drawing correctly. It seems that as soon as `[my_line[0] render]` executes, all other objects disappear. What do I do to correct this?

Comment: Is `modelViewMatrix` a local or instance variable? If you're not doing anything to the `transform` property of your `GLKBaseEffect` instance (and calling its `prepareToDraw` method after each change and before drawing), you won't see any changes.

Comment: `modelViewMatrix` is a local variable. I added more code to my post so that you can see more of what I am doing. Maybe I'm initializing my array of `Line` objects wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What do I need to do to the `transform` property and where should I be calling `prepareToDraw`. As you can tell, I'm new to this ES 2.0 stuff, so this is the kind of thing that I am struggling with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To draw your lines, you call render, and in render you clear the color buffer. Therefore everything you drew before disappears.

Comment: Thanks. Even when I take out those clear color buffer lines, I still get no lines to draw. My error message went away, though...